# Searching for specific values with an array of hashes

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to find a way to pass the following test but i keep end up using loops within loops which are awful. Can anyone help? Here is the test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Promotion_Check do

  let(:check) { Promotion_Check.new rules_list }
  let(:item_rule) { {rule_type: "item", item_code: 1, number_of_items: 2, new_item_price: 8.50} }
  let(:total_rule)  { {rule_type: "total", total_price_break: 60.00, discount_percentage: 10} }
  let(:rules_list) { [ 1 => item_rule, 2 => total_rule ] }

  describe "#applicable_item_rules" do
    it "finds the rules that apply to the baskets items" do
      item_code = 1
      count = 2
      expect(check.applicable_item_rules(item_code, count)).to eq [item_rule]
    end
  end
end
```

Basically, I want to search an array of hashes like so:

```
rules_list = [ 1 => {rule_type: "item", item_code: 1, number_of_items: 2, new_item_price: 8.50}, 2 => {rule_type: "item", item_code: 2, number_of_items: 4, new_item_price: 7.50}]
```

for anything that has a value with a matching :item_code and :number_of_items and push that value into an array.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Because of Ruby being helpful

```
rules_list = [
  1 => {rule_type: "item", item_code: 1, number_of_items: 2, new_item_price: 8.50},
  2 => {rule_type: "item", item_code: 2, number_of_items: 4, new_item_price: 7.50}
]
```

ends up being:

```
 => [{
  1=>{:rule_type=>"item", :item_code=>1, :number_of_items=>2, :new_item_price=>8.5},
  2=>{:rule_type=>"item", :item_code=>2, :number_of_items=>4, :new_item_price=>7.5}
}]
```

which is an array of length 1 containing a hash of length 2. You're better off doing this:

```
rules_list = [
  {rule_type: "item", item_code: 1, number_of_items: 2, new_item_price: 8.50},
  {rule_type: "item", item_code: 2, number_of_items: 4, new_item_price: 7.50}
]
```

and query it like this:

```
rules_list.select { |rule| rule[:item_code] == 1 && rule[:number_of_items] == 2 }

 => [{:rule_type=>"item", :item_code=>1, :number_of_items=>2, :new_item_price=>8.5}]
```